# Conventional way of decrementing an attribute, which action to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, restful-architecture, convention

**If I want to decrement the counter attribute of an object, is it better to add it to the `update` action, or the `destroy` action, or is it better to create a new action?**

To explain better, let's say you have a `Product` and a `CartItem` class, and every time a user adds the same product to her cart, instead of having two copies of the same `CartItem` object, you increment the `amount` attribute of the `CartItem`.

If I want to let users decrement the amount, what should I use? For example, is something like the code below a viable and conventional way of doing this? Or is it better to create a new action?

**View:**

```
...
<%= button_to 'Remove One', [cart_item, remove_one: true], method: :patch %>
...
```

**Controller:**

```
def update
  if params[:remove_one]
    if @cart_item.quantity > 1
      @cart_item.decrement!(:quantity)
      flash[:notice] = "Removed one of #{@cart_item.product.title}"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      destroy
    end
  end

  return
end
```

**Note**: I understand that the title sounds a bit misleading, but I am not looking for a way to decrement an attribute in Rails. What I want to know is, if you have such a requirement, which action do you put that in? **How do you decide what goes in which action?**

**Edit**: Guys I really expected something credible like an example from a well-maintained source-code, a high-rated book, etc. Under these circumstances, unfortunately I won't be able to award the bounty to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a 100% correct answer but from my experience I see two options that are better than your code example:

1. Have a decrement action on the controller and in the controller you use the `decrement_counter` method ([doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-decrement_counter)). This helps if you have concurrent updates on the same model (though that's not usually the case for shopping carts).
2. Have an update method and in the view render a small form:

The view

```
<%= form_for cart_item do |form| %>
 <%= form.hidden_field :quantity, cart_item.quantity-1 %>
 <%= form.submit 'Remove One'
<% end %>
```

In the controller

```
def update
  @cart_item.update(cart_item_params)
  @cart_item.destroy if @cart_item.quantity == 0
  #in the above 
  redirect_to :back
end

def cart_item_params
  params.require(:cart_item).permit(:quantity)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The first option you provide is not related to which action to use for this purpose. And I don't think the second option you provide is a good way to do this. For example, imagine there are two browsers open on the users computer and she has 4 of the same item. If the user clicks on the "Remove" button, she will have 3 items. But if she clicks on the "Remove" button again on the other browser window, nothing will happen. Because the other window also says "Change the quantity to 3". So I don't think that's a better way.

Comment: Then I recommend the 1st option. Have a route like `PATCH /cart/items/:cat_item_id/decrement` and do decrement_counter and destroy if needed. For the 2nd option you could pass a `quantity_delta` parameter and do the update with `cart_item.update(quantity: cart_item.quantity+params[:quantity_delta]`.

Answer (score 0):

add a dedicated method in `CartItem` class...such as

```
##it will return either true or false
def !!update_amount
    ###use if condition if you need  
    if self.quantity > 1
      self.update_attribute :amount,self.amount+=amount-1 
    end
end
```

**use it anywhere you want such as:--**

```
def update
  if params[:remove_one]
   ##call the method to get only true or false
    if @cart_item.update_amount
      flash[:notice] = "Removed one of #{@cart_item.product.title}"
      redirect_to :back
    else
      destroy
    end
  end

  return
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it make sense semantically to have this in a separate method.

You are updating an attribute on a model, which means that you should use the `PATCH` method, and preferably invoke the `update` method per rails' conventions, so in my opinon this separate method invocation should be performed without altering the RESTful routes.

```
before_action :inventory_check, only: :update

def update
  if @cart_item.update
    flash[:notice] = "Updated your cart."
  else
    flash[:error] = "Couldn't update your cart."
  end
  redirect_to :back
end

def destroy
  @cart_item.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Item removed from your cart."
  redirect_to :back
end

private

def inventory_check
  if params[:decrement] && @cart_item.quantity == 1
    redirect_to :destroy
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you `CartItem` object describes the many-to-many relationship between `Product` and `Card`. So when you are adding  a `Product` to a `Cart`, you are just updating (or creating if there isn't one yet) the content of that specific `Production`-`Cart` relationship.

In this sense, I would suggest you to just put the decrement in the `update` method. However, if you want to do some more logic to determine whether this relationship exists or not, you can also create a new method and do all the validations in it.